# Flashtool gives DOWNLOAD OK but the tablet is not booting anyway

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, rom-flashing, device-firmware, stock-rom, flashtool

I flashed the firmware with SP FLASH TOOL and it gived me DOWNLOAD OK, but I cannot boot the tablet anyway

Mediatek: MT8163

Android: 6.0

Comment: Probably because the rom is not compatible with the target device. You need to download another rom and flash it

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded even the preloader.bin your device is done with but if you never ticked preloader that's incompatibility issues between the ROM and the phone